# MongoDB how to become master

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-replication, sharding, mongodb-java

I am creating a MongoDB database through a linux terminal and I am trying to create a collection for the database.

But when I run the command: `db.createCollection("mainCollection")` I get the following error message: `{ "note" : "from execCommand", "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master" }`

I'm not exactly sure what this means. How can I make the database master?

Thanks

Comment: try `rs.slaveOk()` in the mongo shell

Comment: Nope, it is still giving me the same error

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: Mongo 3.0, and the java driver is 3.0.2

Comment: try `db.getCollection("mainCollection")`

Comment: you might also want to try inserting a document into that collection, it'll create it for you if it doesn't already exist

Comment: I tried inserting a document with this command: db.mainCollection.insert({title:'MongoDB'}), but once again, I get the same error.

Comment: what's your connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have started the `mongod` with the [--replSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.replSetName) option (or equivalent configuratin file option). That puts the `mongod` into a mode where it will not allow **any** writes until it receives a replica set configuration.

For an existing replica set this is accomplished by doing a [rs.add("<host>:<port>")](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) on the existing primary for the replica set.

Based on the conversation around this question I think you have a single MongoDB instance and do not plan to have a true multi-member replica set. If that is  the case you have two options:

- Stop trying to run a replica set

  1. Stop the `mongod`.
  2. Wipe the data directory for the `mongod` process.
  3. Restart the `mongod` process without the `--replSet` option on the command line/config.
- Initialize the `mongod` as a single node replica set.

  1. Run [rs.initiate()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) from the shell (no config is required).  You will get disconnected but the shell will automatically reconnect and then you can create collections and do other writes.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the first option.

Comment: When following your steps, I get following error on step "4." (Initialize the mongod as a single node replica set.):

{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
        "code" : 76
}
Makes sense!

So I'd suggest this step is unnecessary?! Or why should you do this? I think it is already initiated as "single node replica set" (when this is the right word...)

Comment: You should do either 1-3 for a standalone mongod _or_ the rs.initiate(), not both.

Answer (score 0):

Thats expected behaviour "Viratan" if you are querying on the replica set and the shell you are connected with is not the Primary.

You can do either of these two things.

1. Disconnect from the current shell and connect with the Primary. In mongo shell you would see it written "PRIMARY" or "SECONDARY".
2. In case you want the same member as the primary then you can increase the priority of that particular member and/or force the formar primary to stepDown. once the primary is step down, the election would occur and because the desired member has higher priority that would become primary.
   you can follow the below link to change the priority of a member http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary

Once you are connected with Primary in either ways, you can query the DB and do your stuff.

Happy Mongoing.. :-)

-$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have not created/initiated a replica set, should I do that first?

Comment: not needed, just for quick dev perspective you install mongo and direct start executing the commands without worrying about replica set or sharding... however this error do come when you are connected with a secondary node and try to do some operation.

Comment: I see. But when I do the command: rs.config(), I get the following error:  Error: Could not retrieve replica set config: {
        "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
        "code" : 94
}

Comment: rs.config() here, rs stands for replicaSet...why u have to run this command.? even in the message it says that cudn't retrieve replica set because there is no replica set...you don't need to run this command until u setup a replica set...the moment you enter the mono console just say [use test] and then [db.t1.save({name:"test"})]...all set.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to create a new collection on secondary.thats why it is giving as error please use primary to create new